# Keycloak not able to start --version 3.4.1.cR1

Tags: keycloak

When Keycloak is trying to start, it is unable to start. The Following error is thrown in the logs :

ERROR

> [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Change Set
>   META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.5.0.xml::1.5.0::bburke@redhat.com failed. 
>   Error: Column "USER_SETUP_ALLOWED" not found; SQL statement: ALTER
>   TABLE PUBLIC.AUTHENTICATION_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN  USER_SETUP_ALLOWED
>   SET DEFAULT NULL [42122-193] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE
>   PUBLIC.AUTHENTICATION_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN  USER_SETUP_ALLOWED SET
>   DEFAULT NULL]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column
>   "USER_SETUP_ALLOWED" not found; SQL statement: ALTER TABLE
>   PUBLIC.AUTHENTICATION_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN  USER_SETUP_ALLOWED SET
>   DEFAULT NULL [42122-193] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE
>   PUBLIC.AUTHENTICATION_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN  USER_SETUP_ALLOWED SET
>   DEFAULT NULL]
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
>           at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247

Comment: Are you upgrading from an older installation ?